# Homebrew says Xcode is out of date but it doesn't show up in the App Store

Tags: xcode, homebrew

When trying to install a homebrew keg, I get the following error:

```
$ brew install direnv

Error: Your Xcode (8.0) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

When I open the app store, Xcode doesn't indicate any software update is available – in fact, it even doesn't appear to be installed.

How can I update (or delete) it?

Comment: You can delete X-code by simply dragging its icon from the Applications folder to the trashcan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/Applications/Xcode.app` exists, but it's not showing up in the App Store as installed, then it's likely you installed Xcode manually by downloading it from [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

You can delete it simply by moving `/Applications/Xcode.app` to the trash. This should allow you to `brew install <package>` without the error.